# Subset based on criteria in sas

Tags: macros, sas, subset

Let's hope I have worded the question correctly.

I have pulled a series of cricketing scorecards and now have 'x' scorecards (datasets) each containing 'n' rows of observations. What I want to do is create 'k' subsets from the 'x' scorecards by automatically dividing each scorecard dataset by 8. (for e.g. one of my scorecards has 168 observations therefore this scorecard will be broken into 21 subsets, while another scorecard contains 128 entries so it will be broken into 16 subsets).

I then want to transpose each of the 'k' subsets, this will then give me a dataset containing one row. Finally I want to stack the 'k' transposed datasets to create one big dataset.

small example:

```
NT Broom
b Henry
21
12
15
3
1
140
JD ryder
b Henry
1
3
2
0
0
50.00
```

(small extract from one of the scorecards) The above dataset will be divided into 2 subsets, then each of the 2 subsets will by transposed to produce the below (2) datasets:

1. `NT Broom b henry 21  12  15  3   1   140.00`
2. `JD Ryder b Henry 1 3 2 0 0 50.00`

The two datasets will be stacked on top of each:

`NT Broom b henry 21 12 15  3   1   140.00`

`JD Ryder b Henry 1 3 2 0 0 50.00`

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance,
Ankit

what I've done some far:

/*Batting Subset Macro*/

```
proc sql;
     select count (8) into:total from compile_bat_cleaned_&match;
 quit;


%macro create_subsets(count,compile_bat_cleaned_665647);
    %let cnt = %sysfunc(ceil(%sysevalf(&count/8)));
    %let num = 1;

    %do i = 1 %to &cnt;
        %if(&i = &cnt) %then %do;
            %let toread = &count;
        %end;
        %else %do;
            %let toread = &num + 7;
         %end;

   data compile_bat_cleaned_665647_&i;
     set compile_bat_cleaned_665647 (firstobs=&num obs=%eval(&toread)); 
   run;

  proc transpose data = compile_bat_cleaned_665647_&i out = compile_bat_cleaned_665647_&i (drop=_name_);         
   var bat_det_2_term details_4;

   data compile_bat_cleaned_665647_&i;
      set compile_bat_cleaned_665647_&i (firstobs = 2);
   rename COL1 = Batsman
          COL2 = Dismissal
          COL3 = Runs_Scored
          COL4 = Minutes
          COL5 = Balls
          COL6 = Fours
          COL7 = Sixes
          COL8 = Strike_Rate;

   %let num = %eval(&num + 8);
  %end;

data batters_merged_665647;
  set 
  %do i = 1 %to &cnt;
    compile_bat_cleaned_665647_&i
  %end;
  ;
run;

%mend create_subsets;

%create_subsets(&total,compile_bat_cleaned_665647);
```

the above piece of code works for individual scorecards (match=665647), but not for a series of scorecard data. I change the macro to %macro `create_subsets(count,compile_bat_cleaned_&match)`
but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? We're not going to do the project for you! Show us the code that you've tried and specifically what is not working.

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely- I've edited my question above and included some of my code

Comment: Listen to Joe, no macro's needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're missing is *by group processing*.  Most things in SAS you don't have to split up into one dataset per ID or anything like that; you assign a ID variable and then do whatever *by* that variable.

In this case, if you have a variable `playerID` that has a 1 for the first 8 rows, then a 2 for the second 8 rows (9-16), etc., then you can proc transpose `by playerID;`, and do just the one transpose, all from one dataset to another single dataset.  No macro, no fuss.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I've got it working with using a macro. Thanks, Ankit